# Jquery array to serialized string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

I have an array that is being populated with the contents of form fields that have a numeric value entered into them.

It generates the array into the following.

```
["21996=1", "17553=1", "17554=1", "13773=1", "13774=1", "17573=1"]
```

now whilst its doing this, my ajax submit is requiring that I serialize a form field with the contents.

Previously it was populating it with every form field, so i decided to loop over the populated contents and now I have the array defined above.

what Im wondering is... How do i go about making this accessible for the form to post as a serialized string ? Ive tried $.param() but it doesnt work to well.

Any ideas ?

```
$.ajax({
           type: "post",
           url: $("#add-all-to-cart").attr('action'),
           data: $("#add-all-to-cart").serialize(), // serializes
                                                   // the form's elements.
           dataType : 'json',
           cache : true,


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var arr1 = ["21996=1", "17553=1", "17554=1", "13773=1", "13774=1", "17573=1"];

$.ajax({
       type: "post",
       url: $("#add-all-to-cart").attr('action'),
       data: $("#add-all-to-cart").serialize() + "&" + arr1.join('&'), // serializes the form's elements.
       dataType : 'json',
       cache : true,


});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$.ajax({
       type: "post",
       url: $("#add-all-to-cart").attr('action'),
       data: ["21996=1", "17553=1", "17554=1", "13773=1", "13774=1", "17573=1"].join('&');
       dataType : 'json',
       cache : true
});
```